# change value of the for variable to go back

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to change the "j" variable in the for lopp, but it keeps running. 
For example, when j == 2 , i want it to "go back" to j = 1.
The j that i want to modify is in the line:
`for (int j=0; j < triangulo1.matrizTriangulo[i].length; j++)`

My variables are in spanish, i'm sorry for that.
Hope can help me guys.

```
public void encontrarTrianguloMayor()
    {

        for (int i=0; i < triangulo1.matrizTriangulo.length; i++)  // For que recorre las filas
        {
            actual = 0;
            for (int j=0; j < triangulo1.matrizTriangulo[i].length; j++)  // For que recorre las columnas
            {
                if (triangulo1.matrizTriangulo[i][j] == '_' ) // Si encuentro un triangulo blanco sumo 1 a actual
                {

                    actual+=1;

                    if (actual > 1 && actual%2 != 0 && actual > total ) // Si actual no es 1 y actual es impar y que el actual > total
                    {

                        ultimoIndiceColumnas = j;
                        primerIndiceColumnas = j - actual + 1;          
                        indiceFilas = i;
                        total = actual;
                        if (verificarTriangulo())
                        {
                            //do nothing
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            j = j - actual + 1;
                            actual = 0;
                        }


                    }

                }

                else if(triangulo1.matrizTriangulo[i][j] == '#')
                {                   
                    actual = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: with `j = j - actual + 1;`, are you taking into account the fact that the for loop will still execute the `j++`?

Comment: @PhilM yes, i did, but when the loop begin again, it doesn't change the value of j, and keep taking the "original j" with the loop.

Comment: What about `verificarTriangulo()`. If this is always true you'd never reduce `j`. Maybe add some debug output?

Comment: @edi that's not always true, i cheked it. Actually, i enter in the else, but j don't want to change.

Comment: Maybe just use a `while (j < triangulo1.matrizTriangulo[i].length) { ... } ` loop to rule out the `for`-issue

Comment: Also your `actual` variable is critical. If `triangulo1.matrizTriangulo[i][j]` contains for example a different character you never might add one to actual and consequently never enter `if (actual > 1 && actual%2 != 0 && actual > total )`